# How can I create a numpy vector of size n containing 0 or 1 randomly?

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I know that `np.zeros(n)` creates an n-dimensional vector containing only zeros in python.

Is there an easy way to get an n-dimensional vector containing randomly zeros or ones as integer values?

I tried to find an answer here but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 3):

There are many options. Here are two possible ways using NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10

np.random.randint(0, 2, size=n)

np.random.choice([0,1], size=n)
```

Both will output something like this:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Here is the relevant documentation:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Comment: Instead of "try", just validate your suggestion by printing the output :)